# GMapsFX not displaying

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, google-maps-api-3

the GMapsFX integration with JavFXML is a very obscure area and I am struggling to find information on the internet.

I find a tutorial [here](https://rterp.wordpress.com/tag/google-maps/) but it still obscure

So basically, Everything seems to be running without major errors but the actual display is "hidden" and I don't know why.

FXML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" 
            prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

As before, there is no use in showing my controller class given that it has no code of relevance.

The error that is outputting is:

```
20:51:00.769 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called
```

Here is the controller class (just in case):

```
package MapPage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class MapPageController implements Initializable {


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }
```

}

Comment: I have added the class

Comment: gave it a go, but the "Alert: hide directions called" still appeared

Comment: any ideas ? @charlesLgn

Comment: okay so a window does appear: but it is just an empty window with an anchor pane and the "GoogleMaps" window is "hidden"

Comment: Completely different errors wouldn't work @cha

Comment: what version do you use ? seams to work on 2.10.0

Comment: Work on 2.10.0? Of what

Comment: Basically the dependencies that I have for the GMapsFX-2.12.0 are slfj-api-1.7.23 and logback-classic-1.2.1 and logback-core-1.2.1. This was the only combinations of libraries that allowed me to run the program and display some sort of window - but the now I have this "alert" when trying the open the window which contains a GoogleMapView and and Anchor pane but it only shows the anchor pane.

Comment: @charlesLgn .....

Comment: weirdly I just switched the GMapsFX 2.12.0 with 2.10.0 and the error didn't appear but the same window appeard (the anchor pane but no GoogleMapView)

Comment: if you have given it a go can you tell me what dependencies you have used and I can try it with them - I genuinely think this is the issue.

Comment: basicly i use maven to not be disturbed by all these dependencies.

Comment: no you can transforme a project as maven . have a look on the internet.

Comment: https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!!
Have to upgrade to Java 11 and JavaFX 11 so the map can be displayed.
Also, according to this [thread](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/issues/175), upgrading to jdk1.8.0_181 helps too.

Comment: That's great! Do you have a link to downloads?

Comment: Java 11 is on Oracle website
JavaFX 11 can be found here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: so I recently started a different project but came back to my GMapsFX project and realised you had the solution - however after further reading I still am not able to figure it out? Yes I get updating to JavaFX 11 but it does not actually use JavaFX and my project is getting all messed up when trying to use it. you got any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using Java 11 and JavaFX 11. The configuration to use JavaFX11 should be done in Project Build Path

Comment: I'm using NetBeansIDE and its a little complicated. what IDE where you using

Comment: I use Eclipse. Try consider JavaFX11 the same as any of your external libraries. It should work the same way

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question regarding it, take a look if you can.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add javafx.web to your VM options. Thats what worked for me.